# Quoting a list of comma separated string literals?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of literals like this (These are unquoted strings - not variables):

```
alice-blue, antique-white, aqua, ...
```

And I want them to be quoted like this (For use in a nunjucks loop):

```
'alice-blue', 'antique-white', 'aqua', ...
```

Look for a simple way to do this in javascript.

Comment: unclear what you want and what the problem is. Make an example

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. You should know this by now.

Comment: What do you mean by list of values ? Is that an array or string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "alice-blue, antique-white, aqua";
var arr = str.split(', ');
for(var i=0; i< arr.length;i++){
   arr[i] = "'"+arr[i]+"'";
}
var resultStr = arr.join(", ");
```